# How to display years on x axis line plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm trying to plot some data using `pandas` and `matplotlib`.

Consider this data:

```
years = [i for i in range(2005, 2016)]
values = [49.929266640000002, 45.441518010000003, 49.762879810000001, 52.849612180000001, 57.618790150000002, 47.750615240000002, 47.508212309999998, 37.414841590000002, 45.441518010000003, 47.750615240000002, 49.929266640000002]
```

if I plot the data:

```
lineplt = pandas.Series(values, name='Some City 2005 - 2015')
lineplt.index = years
lineplt.plot(title = 'Rate some city 2005 - 2015', legend=True)
```

Everything goes ok as image:

[image]

However, if try a period less than 11 years `x axis` doesn't display years:

Fo example, consider this data:

```
years = [i for i in range(2008, 2016)]
values = [49.929266640000002, 45.441518010000003, 49.762879810000001, 52.849612180000001, 57.618790150000002, 47.750615240000002, 47.508212309999998, 37.414841590000002]
lineplt = pandas.Series(values, name='Some city 2008 - 2015')
lineplt.index = years
lineplt.plot(title = 'Rate some city 2008 - 2015', legend=True)
```

It shows:

[image]

Is there a solution, maybe some argument or parameter I missing, in order to display years from 2008 to 2015 and not the index as single number?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix your problem is to explicitly use `datetime` objects as your index. Pandas provides a utility for this:

```
years = pd.date_range('2008','2015', freq='AS')
```

The `freq` parameter takes an offset. You can create your own or use one of the [built-in aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

Comment: Thanks! It was easy. I made: `lineplt.index = pandas.date_range('2008','2015', freq='AS')` and it works great!

Comment: @estebanpdl yes, I frequently refer to that link.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like that:

```
fig = plt.figure()                                                               
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)    

ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
ax.set_xlim((2008, 2016))
```

Comment: Thanks, Vasya. This time I'll go for the first answer. Just one line.